# Entity Framework Two foreign keys as primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So i am working with entity code firest and i have a user class that looks like this:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to make a "friends table" and no matter what i come up with I get an error on the db creation. This is what I Currently have in the Friends Class:

```
public class Friend
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
        public virtual User MyUser { get; set; }

        [Key,ForeignKey("User")]
        public virtual User MyFriend { get; set; }

        public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the error i get:

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'MyUser' on type 'Core.Model.Friend' is not valid. The foreign key name 'User' was not found on the dependent type 'Core.Model.Friend'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Column` attribute. Normally I would use something like this:

```
public class Friend
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int MyUserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int MyFriendId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MyUserId")]
    public virtual User MyUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FriendId")]
    public virtual User MyFriend { get; set; }

    public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure what would happen if you map the `Column` attribute directly to the navigation property. You can try it if you like and see what happens.. but the above generally works for me.

Alternatively, if you change to use fluent mapping, you can do something like this:

```
HasKey(u => new { u.MyUserId , u.MyFriendId });
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but i changed the ints to strings because my user class key is a string. When I did that, I now get a cyclical reference error from the db.

Comment: This helped me fix a dreaded, "can't find Table_ID column" error.